# How can I execute a spock Specification using groovy and produce junit xml file

Tags: groovy, command-line, spock

I have a Spock specification that I can execute directly on the commandline using the `groovy` executable. This works because the specification class delegates to the `sputnik` test runner, which delegates to the junit 4 runner.

The output I receive is a textual result. Instead, I would like to receive a JUnit xml result file. I am trying to use the direct script execution and avoid the use of maven and gradle as I want this to be light-weight.

Can someone please let me know how I can configure the system to provide this result?

Answer (score 0):

Spock doesn't generate reports like this, its Surefire in maven world (or its gradle counterpart) that run the tests, gather the results and generate the reports. I assume you're talking about target/surefire-reports folder.

Now there are two ways:

1. Run the maven's surefire plugin directly. Something like `mvn surefire:test` won't compile anything (assuming you've already compiled code and tests) and only will run tests. You can also filter to run one specific test / specify wildcards, read surefire plugin documentation.
2. Spock has a concept of Listeners. These listeners are called during the test lifecycle and you can provide hooks to gather results by yourself and when the test finishes (no matter successfully or with failure - you'll have a hook) - create a file with the information and it will be your report).

There are projects that work exactly this way, altough they do not produce an XML in the form the surefire does it:
[spock-reports](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports)
[damage-control](https://github.com/tprado/damage-control-report)

Comment: I understand that spoc tests are adapted to JUnit 4 test cases. As such, they would have a limited interface that conforms to Test in Junit. As a consequence a JUnit4 runner should be able to perform and report on the execution in XML. Please note that I am familiar with means to perform Spock tests using Jupiter under Maven. I just do not want an additional component for this case.
You can see a demand-based adaptation here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-test/src/main/java/groovy/util/AllTestSuite.java